# Make R2DBC use the same connection for all interactions with the database in a @Transactional method (Java, Sprint)

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

#### Motivation

I have a service which I want to make `@Transactional`. My service is storing complex data in multiple tables, there is a referential integrity between the tables.

```java
public class MyData { // simplified
    MasterData masterData;
    List<Detail> details;

    public static class MasterData {
        UUID id;
        String field1;
        String field2;
        String field3;
    }

    public static class Detail {
        UUID masterId;
        String fieldA;
        String fieldB;
    }
}
```

1. First I save the master data into one table using `R2dbcRepository<MasterData, UUID>`. The `INSERT` command is simple and I may use the `R2dbcRepository`.
2. Then a list of details into another table using `DatabaseClient`. Each detail has a foreign key constraint to the master table. I want to use batch `INSERT` and I complete the SQL using more complex approach in `DatabaseClient`.

#### Problem

The problem is that I cannot save the detail data - I get the error

```plaintext
insert or update on table "detail" violates foreign key constraint
```

I suspect that the reason is that each SQL command is executed in **a different connection** so the master data are not yet visible when the details are stored.

#### Question

**Is it really the root cause? How to make R2DBC always use the same connection across all the calls to the database inside one `@Transactional` service call, even if it goes via various instances of `R2dbcRepository` and `DatabaseClient`?**

If the solution is completely wrong, how to correctly implement `@Transactional` in R2DBC?

I prefer calling all the `INSERT`s into the `detail` table in a batch.

#### Code

My (simplified) code looks like this:

```java
@Service
public class MyService {
    private final MasterRepository masterRepository;
    private final DbConnector dbConnector;

    @Transactional
    public Mono<Void> saveMasterAndDetails(MyData data) {
        return Mono.just(data)
                .map(MyData::getMaster)
                .flatMap(masterRepository::insertMasterData)
                .thenReturn(data)

                .map(MyData::getDetails)
                .flatMap(dbConnector::insertDetails)
                .then()
                ;
    }
}
```

The code of `MasterRepository` is something like

```java
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.R2dbcRepository;

public interface MasterRepository extends R2dbcRepository<MasterData, UUID> {
    @Query("""
            INSERT INTO master(id, col_1, col_2, col_3)
                VALUES (
                    :#{#masterData.id},
                    :#{#masterData.field1},
                    :#{#masterData.field2},
                    :#{#masterData.field3})
            """)
    Mono<Void> insertMasterData(MasterData masterData);
}
```

And the code of `DbConnector` is more complex - but maybe overly complex? There is still missing direct support for batches and prepared statements in `DatabaseClient`: [spring-data-r2dbc-259](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/259), [spring-framework-27229](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27229)

```java
import org.springframework.r2dbc.core.DatabaseClient;
import io.r2dbc.spi.Connection;
import io.r2dbc.spi.Statement;

public class DbConnector {
    private final DatabaseClient databaseClient;

    public Mono<Integer> insertDetails(List<Detail> details) {
        // usingWhen() is the reactive analogy of "use-with-resources"
        return Flux.usingWhen(
                // "try(Create the resource)"
                databaseClient.getConnectionFactory().create(),

                // "{ the body }"
                connection -> {
                    final Statement statement = connection.createStatement("""
                            insert into detail (masterId, col_A, col_B)
                            values ($1, $2, $3)
                            """);
                    details.forEach(detail ->
                            statement
                                    .bind("$1", detail.getMasterId())
                                    .bind("$2", detail.getColA())
                                    .bind("$3", detail.getColB())
                                    .add()
                    );
                    return statement.execute();
                },

                // "finally close()"
                Connection::close)

        .flatMap(Result::getRowsUpdated)
        .reduce(0, Integer::sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

I replaced

```java
return Flux.usingWhen(
    databaseClient.getConnectionFactory().create(),

    connection -> {
        statement = ... // prepare the statement
        return statement.execute();
    },

    Connection::close
)
```

with

```java
return databaseClient.inConnection(connection -> {
    statement = ... // prepare the statement
    return statement.execute();
);
```

#### Detailed answer

I have discovered a method which I was not aware of: [DatabaseConnection.inConnection()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/r2dbc/core/ConnectionAccessor.html#inConnection-java.util.function.Function-). The `DatabaseConnection` interface inherits it from `ConnectionAccessor`:

> Execute a callback Function within a Connection scope. The function is responsible for creating a Mono. The connection is released after the Mono terminates (or the subscription is cancelled). Connection resources must not be passed outside of the Function closure, otherwise resources may get defunct.

I changed my code using the `DatabaseClient` and it seems that the SQL commands are executed in the same connection.

However, I would still like to understand it better. I am not sure, if I am just lucky now and if it can change with the next implementation. I still do not know how to have the full control over the connections and hence over the transactional code.

```java
import org.springframework.r2dbc.core.DatabaseClient;
import io.r2dbc.spi.Connection;
import io.r2dbc.spi.Statement;

public class DbConnector {
    private final DatabaseClient databaseClient;

    public Mono<Integer> insertDetails(List<Detail> details) {
        return databaseClient.inConnection(connection -> {
            final Statement statement = connection.createStatement("""
                insert into detail (masterId, col_A, col_B)
                values ($1, $2, $3)
                """);
            details.forEach(detail ->
                statement
                    .bind("$1", detail.getMasterId())
                    .bind("$2", detail.getColA())
                    .bind("$3", detail.getColB())
                    .add()
            );
            return Flux.from(statement.execute())
                .flatMap(Result::getRowsUpdated)
                .reduce(0, Integer::sum)
                ;
    });
}
```